# JSLint: was used before it was defined in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint

JSLint warns on variable in anomymous function

```
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then(ref => {
   console.log(ref)
})
```

Warning in first line: 'ref' was used before it was defined.

How to fix it?

Comment: Probably an issue with how JSLint handles asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a little late to the party, but the quick version is...

Well, the quick version is I think you're using an out of date version of JSLint.

But if you update it or go to [jslint.com](http://jslint.com), **then** the quick version is...

JSLint does not like using `=>` format for function except in a *very* specific circumstance: You're immediately returning something.

#### Linting all but the fart (arrow function)

This version of your code *nearly* lints:

```
/*jslint single */
/*global db, docId, userData */
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then(ref => {
   console.log(ref);
});
```

- Single quote use requires the `single` `jslint` directive.
- Out of context, I made `db`, `docId`, and `userData` all globals.
- Needed a few `;` to end lines.

#### Fart errors

Now we're down to this:

```
Wrap the parameter in parens.
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then(ref => {
```

But doing so might confuse you, as you get another error:

```
/*jslint single */
/*global db, docId, userData */
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then((ref) => {
   console.log(ref);
});

Expected 'function' and instead saw '=>'.
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then((ref) => {
```

---

#### Why it's this way...

As we read [from JSLint's instructions](https://jslint.com/help.html#function):

> Finally, ES6 provides an even shorter form of function expression that leaves out the words `function` and `return`:
>
> `(parameters) => expression`
>
> JSLint requires the parens around the parameters, and forbids a `{` left brace after the `=>` fart to avoid syntactic ambiguity.

No squigglies allowed! JSLint demands you have a single line that returns something. (A `{` might seem to mean you're returning an object literal, which would be confusing -- is it an object literal or a multi-line function body? So JSLint doesn't allow `{` at all.)

Now in your case, you're not actually returning anything, but `console.log` will immediately return `undefined`, so JSLint will allow it. You tricked it.

```
/*jslint single, browser */
/*global db, docId, userData, console */
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then((ref) => console.log(ref));
```

Success. Though evil success.

By the way, this means that `ref` is fine.

<sub>The reason you probably saw the error you did is b/c your older version of JSLint had no concept of es6 at all. Or, if it did, it's old enough to require_ you to use the `es6` jslint directive, which has since been removed as a valid directive.</sub>

#### But what JSLint really wants in your case is `function`

But if you had *two* console.log calls, it wouldn't.

```
/*jslint single, browser */
/*global db, docId, userData, console */
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then((ref) => {
  console.log(ref); 
  console.log(ref + "another");
});

Expected 'function' and instead saw '=>'.
```

What JSLint really wants (and what you avoid in your specific case **only b/c you only have a single line in the fart**) is this...

```
/*jslint single, browser */
/*global db, docId, userData, console */
db.collection('users').doc(docId).set(userData).then(function (ref) {
    console.log(ref);
});
```